# C++ How can i match strings with the same relative position to an input?

Tags: c++, find, match

I am currently using this code to match string:

```
priority_queue<TreeNode> wordQueue; // declaration of wordQueue

struct TreeNode {  //declaration of TreeNode
    string key;
    int data;
};

if (wordQueue.top().key.find(a) != string::npos){  //a is a string input from the user
    inputMatches.push_back(wordQueue.top());
}
```

The code searches a queue for any string that matches an input. It does matches correctly. However it matches any string in the queue that contains the input. for example input "hi" it would match with "hi", "this", "high", "thigh" etc.  How could I make it so that it matches strings that contain the input in the same relative position so for the above example it would only match with "hi" and "high"

Comment: `if(wordQueue.top().key.find(a) == 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a

```
std::string needle;
```

then,

```
needle.size()
```

is the number of characters in `needle`.

If you are not familiar with the `size()` method, it should be explained somewhere in any book on C++.

If you then have a

```
std::string haystack;
```

then

```
haystack.substr(0, needle.size());
```

gives you the initial `needle.size()` characters from the `haystack`.

If you are not familiar with the `substr()` method, it should be explained somewhere in any book on C++.

Therefore:

```
if (haystack.substr(0, needle.size()) == needle)
```

is true, then the initial contents of `haystack` are the same as `needle`'s. So, in your case, if `needle` contains "hi", it will find it in the `haystack`, if the `haystack` contains "high", or "hi", but not "this".

It should then be clear to you, now, how you need to change your own code to look for your particular needle in your particular haystack.

Answer (score 0):

when you say "string A matches string B in the same relative order" you actually mean of one of the below:

1. A is a prefix of B
2. B is a prefix of A

therefore you should compare with:

```
strcmp(A, B, min(strlen(A), strlen(B) )
```

which actually compares up to the length of the shortest of them

Answer (score 0):

Could try the compare() method. You can restrict the matching interval to the length of the input `a`. compare() returns 0 for match.

```
if (wordQueue.top().key.compare(0, a.length(), a) == 0) ...
```